# Do I have the right graphics driver?

Tags: 11.10, graphics, intel-graphics

I just did a clean install of Kubuntu 11.10.

How do I find out whether the best graphics driver is installed, and how can I install what's needed?

The question is rather specific but is there a general command that says: "Yes, you have the right driver?

```
$ lspci
...
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (primary) (rev 0c)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (secondary) (rev 0c)
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some graphic cards have open source drivers and proprietary ones (ATI and nVidia, to be more precise). The "right driver" might depend on your model and on what you are trying to run, as they may provide different performance.

As you are on *Kubuntu*, I am posting `glxinfo` commands that would test Unity 3D support (equivalent to `/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p`):

```
glxinfo | grep -i rendering
glxinfo | grep -i fbconfig
glxinfo | grep -i texture_from_pixmap
glxinfo | grep -i vertex_program
glxinfo | grep -i fragment_program
glxinfo | grep -i vertex_buffer
glxinfo | grep -i framebuffer_object
glxinfo | grep -i "glx version"
```

If you have output for all of those, you should be able to run Unity 3D. It is not like a stress test to run a specific app, but lets you know about basic 3D support.

Comment: I hinted that I don't have Unity when I said *Kubuntu*. Does `glxinfo | grep rendering` --> `direct rendering: Yes` tell me the same?

Comment: Thanks, by the way, you mentioning 3D support helped me search for things!

Comment: @Unapiedra updated answer according to your comment. Thanks for pointing you are running Kubuntu... my mistake back there.